# How could a server know if it is connecting with a particular app via tcp or not?

Tags: authentication, web-application, network, wifi, attacks

If a particular app being developed uses tcp to connect with a server, how could the server be sure that the connection is being made from that app? I know that sources can be easily spoofed and destinations can be gained from packets by sniffing, but how could an app differentiate its packets from a sender not using the app?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You can't know.  It's impossible.

Comment: Just add message authentication code (MAC) to your app.  For example, you might HMAC messages and send the signature with them; then the server confirms that the signature matches the message, or else it rejects the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to be sure that the traffic is coming from a specific app.  Since the app is in the control of the user, the user can always make their own application that acts the same as the application that was intended for the server.  There are ways to make it harder for someone to do this and I can provide more details if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can have mutual authentication through a variety of mechanisms:

1. Client based SSL/TLS certificates unique to the app built in that clients must use for connection/authentication. [Example in IIS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiohKLy263VAhWTwYMKHfxcClgQFgg8MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.iis.net%2Ft%2F1207518.aspx%3FCreating%2BClient%2BCertificate%2Band%2BValidating%2Bon%2BIIS%2B7%2B5&usg=AFQjCNG9m9MrT-2EOlV7lPZ_4O3NxOXu4w)
2. As Nat mentioned, HMAC and other implementations [Example for Android Dev](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Mac.html)
3. If you're speaking in terms of a 'pure' TCP connection there really isn't much at L4-- but I guess if you don't want to do it at L7 you could do something like a TCP/IP stack fingerprint on L2-L4 attributes for that session and match it with some sort of minimum confidence rating based on what the app would push down the stack on a legitimate client. [P0f](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/) might be something of interest if you're doing this a L4.